# How to search by 2 parameters at the same moment using UISearchBar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I'm using a UISearchBar for searching users. User has a username and displayname. Now I use this code for searching by parameter "username", how to search by "displayname" too, at the same moment? Search result should contains both parameters

```
var timer: Timer?
var filteredUsers = [User]()
var users = [User]()
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            self?.filteredUsers = (self?.users)!
        } else {
            self?.filteredUsers = (self?.users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
                return user.username.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
                })!
        }
        self?.tableView?.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering your users, you just need to include both conditions for your check using the 'or' logical operator. Make your filtered results look something like this:

```
self?.filteredUsers = (self?.users.filter { (user) -> Bool in
    return (
        user.username.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ||
        user.displayname.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    )
})!
```